# Re-render 'replica' buttons based on array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dom, createelement

I have an app with 14 buttons. When you click on any of the buttons, this creates another button with the same inner text.

All of the pre-existing buttons have a number class that helps me iterate over them. I'm trying to make it so that when two or more of these buttons are clicked, it organises the new 'replica' buttons in ascending order from left to right.

As it stands, my code orders the first two 'replica' buttons correctly, but it ignores the order when you click three or more pre-existing buttons in total.

I suspect this happens because the loop is broken once the buttons are initially rendered, but I can't figure a way around this. Can you help?

Here is the section of code that I think is causing the issue:

```
function orderButtons(array) {

for (i in array) {
let sideElements = array[i];
  if (array.length >= 2) {
   sortNumbers(array);

   /*let classArray = this.className.split(' ')
   let buttonNum = +(classArray[0]);
   let index = sideArray.indexOf(buttonNum);*/

     choiceButtons(sideButtons[sideElements].textContent);
     console.log(array);

  }
 }
}
```

Edit: Here is another section of the code which could be causing the issue:

```
function choiceButtons(innerText) {

  //create button

if (intervalArray.indexOf(innerText) === -1) {
  let choiceBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  //chooseDiv.style.visibility ="hidden";

//document.getElementById('start-button').disabled = true;  //add inner text to choice buttons
  choiceBtn.textContent = innerText;

  //append to choice-buttons-div
  document.getElementById("choice-buttons-div").appendChild(choiceBtn);
  choiceBtn.className = "choice-buttons";
      //push innerText to array
    intervalArray.push(innerText);
      console.log(intervalArray);
      let childNodes = chooseDiv.childNodes;
      console.log(intervalArray);

    }
  }
```

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/david-webb/pen/abNmbVm?editors=1010

I've added a clear function to temporarily remove the buttons. I then call the orderButtons function to try and re-render the buttons, but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to your codepen, it seems you always clear your "replica" when more than two buttons are selected:

```
if (sideArray.length > 2) {
    document.getElementById('clear').click();
    orderButtons(sideArray);
}
```

Moreover, your clear function only remove DOM node, but never clear your `intervalArray` used in `choiceButtons` in order to generate your "replica"

Comment: Thanks qphi. I did that in an attempt to re-render the buttons using the orderButtons function. This is because without that clear function, it only ever renders the first two buttons in the right (ascending) order. I can't see how it will make a difference if I clear the intervalArray - even without it, the buttons still get rendered. Can you shed some light on this, please?

Comment: To illustrate the point about the section you highlighted, I've commented it out. However, I'm still getting the same issue with the rendering order.

Comment: You should probably create a `renderNodes()` function whose render all replica using `intervalArray` (append them to `#choice-buttons-div`), use `choiceButtons()` only to insert button into `intervalArray`. When you click on a "repicable" button, call first `removeAllChildNodes()` then `choiceButtons()` if needed, sort `intervalArray` by classname, and finally call `renderNodes()`. In this case `clear()` will be used only for remove all nodes and reset `intervalArray`